# Flexible relative value calculation in python / ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use the value of df.d to define the row from which I calculate the relative value by using the formula `df.a/df.a[x]` while x is defined as df.d. But somehow this doesn't work. My approach so far is this one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

randn = np.random.randn
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=10, freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0], 'b': [1.1, 1.7, 1.3, 1.6, 1.5, 1.1, 1.5, 1.7, 2.1, 1.9],'c':[None] * 10},index=rng)


df["d"]= [0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,8,8]
df["c"] =df.a/df.a[df.d]
```

All I get is the error: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`
 
To clarify this: I want to set `df.a/df.a[0]` for the first 4 rows, `df.a/df.a[4]` for the next 4 and `df.a/df.a[8]` for the last 2 rows according to `df["d"]= [0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,8,8]`
So how can I refer to a value in the dataframe correcty, without getting this error?

The output I seek looks like this:

```
              a    b     c                       d
2011-01-01  1.1  1.1  1                          0   #  df.a/df.a[0] 
2011-01-02  1.2  1.7  1.090909090909091          0   #  df.a/df.a[0] 
2011-01-03  1.3  1.3  1.181818181818182          0   #  df.a/df.a[0] 
2011-01-04  1.4  1.6  1.272727272727273          0   #  df.a/df.a[0] 
2011-01-05  1.5  1.5  1                          4   #  df.a/df.a[4] 
2011-01-06  1.6  1.1  1.066666666666667          4   #  df.a/df.a[4] 
2011-01-07  1.7  1.5  1.133333333333333          4   #  df.a/df.a[4] 
2011-01-08  1.8  1.7  1.2                        4   #  df.a/df.a[4] 
2011-01-09  1.9  2.1  1                          8   #  df.a/df.a[8] 
2011-01-10  2.0  1.9  1.052631578947368          8   #  df.a/df.a[8]
```

The pandas version used is 0.16.0

Thanks a lot for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to your original Error, I get a different error -

`Unsupported Iterator Index`.  That's 'cos I am trying to get values from df.a at an index which is a series (`df.d`) and not an Index value. (I've pandas version 0.13.1), but to solve your actual problem -

Here's how I could go about it.

```
df['d'] = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,8,8], index=rng)
x = df.a.iloc[df.d]
```

note here - `x` you get has a different date `index`  so simply

```
df['c'] = df.a/x # incorrect
```

won't work. we are only interested in values - so we take them out and assign (ignoring the index).

```
df['c'] = df.a/x.values # We ignore the index of 'x'
```

or as a short form

```
df['c'] = df.a/df.a.iloc[df.d].values
```

What is not clear to me yet is - even though the index of `df.d` is correct why simple `df.a.iloc` won't work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: maybe you have also an idea for level 2 of that problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682918/how-to-calculate-if-statement-for-relative-value-rebalancing-error-the-truth

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use this instead of your last line:

```
df["c"] = df.a.values / df.a[df.d].values
print df
```

Which yields:

```
              a    b      c  d
2011-01-01  1.1  1.1  1.000  0
2011-01-02  1.2  1.7  1.091  0
2011-01-03  1.3  1.3  1.182  0
2011-01-04  1.4  1.6  1.273  0
2011-01-05  1.5  1.5  1.000  4
2011-01-06  1.6  1.1  1.067  4
2011-01-07  1.7  1.5  1.133  4
2011-01-08  1.8  1.7  1.200  4
2011-01-09  1.9  2.1  1.000  8
2011-01-10  2.0  1.9  1.053  8
```

The reason you had an error is because two series you tried to divide one by another had different indexes (not aligned ones). Adding `.values` gets rid of the indexes and solves the issue.

Comment: That results in: `IndexError: unsupported iterator index `

Comment: Works for me without any errors. Which pandas version are you using?